# ngOnInit() doesn't activate login.html

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm trying to make a login page in Nativescript and Angular 9 based app.
I have confirmed that user input and triggering API responses are working but there are a few problems.

login.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Login } from "../login/login";
import { LoginComponent } from "../login/login.component";

@Injectable()
export class LoginService{
    username: string;
    password: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getToken(): Observable<Login[]> {
        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            })
        };

        return this.http.get<Login[]>("http://192.168.20.9/login/token.php?username="+this.username+"&password="+this.password+"&service=moodle_mobile_app/", httpOptions);
    }
}
```

login.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class Login {
    token: string;
    privatetoken: string;

    constructor() {}
}
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { RadSideDrawer } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer";
import * as app from "tns-core-modules/application";

import { LoginService } from "./login.service";
import { Login } from "../login/login";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import * as ApplicationSettings from "@nativescript/core/application-settings";

@Component({
    selector: "Login",
    templateUrl: "./login.component.html"
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    token: Login[];
    input: any;

    constructor(private router: RouterExtensions, private loginService: LoginService, private user: Login) {
        // Use the component constructor to inject providers.
        this.input = {
            "username": "",
            "password": ""
        };
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // if (!ApplicationSettings.getBoolean("authenticated", false)) {
        //     this.router.navigate(["/home"], { clearHistory: true });
        // } // if user is authenticated, go to home

        this.loginService.getToken().subscribe(token => {
            this.token = token;
        });
    }

    onDrawerButtonTap(): void {
        const sideDrawer = <RadSideDrawer>app.getRootView();
        sideDrawer.showDrawer();
    }

    getToken() {
        console.log("page opened");
    }

    login() {
        if(this.input.username && this.input.password) {
            this.loginService.username = this.input.username;
            this.loginService.password = this.input.password;

            console.log(this.loginService.username);
            console.log(this.loginService.password);

            this.loginService.getToken().subscribe(token => {
                this.token = token;
            });

            console.log(this.token);

            if (this.token != null) {
                ApplicationSettings.setBoolean("authenticated", true);
                this.router.navigate(["/home"], { clearHistory: true });

            } else {
                console.log("Incorrect Credentials!");
                this.router.navigate(["/login"], { clearHistory: true });
            }
        } else {
            console.log("All Fields Required!");
        }
    }
}
```

login.component.html

```
<FlexboxLayout>
    <StackLayout>
        <TextField class="input" hint="Username" [(ngModel)]="input.username" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>

        <TextField class="input" hint="Password" [(ngModel)]="input.password" secure="true"></TextField>

        <Button [text]="'Sign In'" (tap)="login()"></Button>

        <StackLayout *ngIf="token">
            <Label text="User token"></Label>
            <Label [text]="token.token"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

## **Here are my questions --Edited**

**1. How to call a function when a user hits the 'sign in' button not when a user opened the login page.**

I'd like to call this function when a user hits the 'Sign in' button not when the user opened the login page.
At the moment when I open the login page, the function gets called with undefined value (because the user hasn't entered anything yet),

[image]

but when I comment out

```
ngOnInit(){
        // this.loginService.getToken().subscribe(token => {
        //    this.token = token;
        // });
}
```

login.html loads nothing. (just blank page).

**2. How to store 'token' value from API call.**

token values have been retrieved from API

and I want to store "token" array and use it for checking user validation.

For example,

when `username == password` in API,

```
{"token: "xxx",  
   "privatetoken": "xxxx"}
```

when `username != password`,

```
{
"error": "Invalid login, please try again",
"errorcode": "invalidlogin",
"stacktrace": "* line 105 of /login/token.php: moodle_exception thrown\n",
"debuginfo": "\nError code: invalidlogin",
"reproductionlink": "http://192.168.20.9/"
}
```

so I want to authenticate the user IF the token has 'token' title in the arrays, not error titles like 'error', 'errorcode', or 'debuginfo' etc.

something like,

```
if(this.token[0].token != null) { dosomething.authenticate user }
```

but it says the array value is not defined and cannot use the data.

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.token[0].token')
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please describe the the exact question..

Comment: @surendrakumar thanks for reading my post. I've numbered my questions as, 1. How to call a function when a user hits the 'sign in' button. and 2. How to store 'token' value from API call. Let me know if I need to clarify more.

Comment: @LucyHong hit the 'sign in' button is (click)="login()", and store the token inside the localStorage.

Comment: @hussain Thanks for the response. executing the function is working okay just want to remove the function with empty values in ngOnInit() and have it only in longin() without having an error. Also want to store the token from the executed array into local variable. something like `validtoken = this.token[0].token;`

Answer (score 0):

Edit your login method

```
login() {
        if(this.input.username && this.input.password) {
            this.loginService.username = this.input.username;
            this.loginService.password = this.input.password;

            console.log(this.loginService.username);
            console.log(this.loginService.password);

            this.loginService.getToken().subscribe(token => {
                this.token = token;
console.log(this.token);

            if (this.token != null) {
                ApplicationSettings.setBoolean("authenticated", true);
                this.router.navigate(["/home"], { clearHistory: true });

            } else {
                console.log("Incorrect Credentials!");
                this.router.navigate(["/login"], { clearHistory: true });
            }
        } 
            });

            else {
            console.log("All Fields Required!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've tried and it doesn't make any difference. I still have to keep `this.loginService.getToken().subscribe(token => { this.token = token; });` in ngOnInit() to view the login page and unable to store token value from the array.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to trigger a function on a button/layout/text use

   (tap)="onlogin()"
   and done.
2. ngOnInit() usually gets called whenever a component is rendered.
   it works also fine when ngOnInit(){} //is empty unless you have any dependency with .html
   you need to swap username,password values to the login service, you could use getter/setter or just

   this.loginService.username = this.username;
   this.loginService.password = this.password;

Also you need to store the response token in the loginservice for future use.

login.ts //interface for login response from api

```
    export interface Login{
    token: string,
    token_two: string    
}
```

this will solve the undefined error

Comment: @adiya_adi_98 Thanks for your response. I guess my question wasn't very clear for the readers. I've edited my question and hope it sounds making sense this time. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to restructure my code entirely and making some good progress.

1. How to call a function when a user hits the 'sign in' button not when a user opened the login page.

This has been resolved and it might've been because of silly mistake in .html.

```
<Button [text]="'Sign In'" (tap)="login()"></Button>
```

"sign in" was in the wrong format. I fixed it as,

```
<Button text="Sign In" (tap)="login()"></Button>
```

then the login.html page loads okay with an empty ngOnInit(). Not 100% sure whether this was causing the issue but definately needs to be fixed.

I haven't figure out how to solve number 2. but I am approaching with a different way based on another tutorial. I will post the solution in case someone wants to see other ways to do it.